# How to implement an Observable as a subset collection of a BehaviorSubject collection

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables, behaviorsubject

I have a BehaviorSubject of pictures (because I need .getValue() in some cases), and an Observable representing the pictures marked as favorite, which is a subset of the pictures. My code works, and here it is :

```
public pictures: BehaviorSubject<Array<Picture>>;
public favoritesPictures: Observable<Array<Picture>>;

constructor(private http: Http) { 
    this.pictures = new BehaviorSubject([]);
    this.favoritesPictures = Observable.create((observer) => {
        this.pictures.subscribe((pictures) => {
            observer.next(pictures.filter((p) => p.isFavorite));
        });
    });
}
```

However I feel like this syntax is quite "heavy", is there a cleaner way to bind an Observable as a subset of a BehaviorSubject ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try following. BehaviorSubject is Observable.

```
public pictures: BehaviorSubject<Array<Picture>>;
public favoritesPictures: Observable<Array<Picture>>;

constructor(private http: Http) { 
    this.pictures = new BehaviorSubject([]);
    this.favoritesPictures = this.pictures.map((a) => a.filter((p) => p.isFavorite));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's a good idea, however in this snippet, `p` is Array<Picture> so it does not have `isFavorite` property

Comment: Yes that's that, thank you. Do you know what the difference is if I add `.share()` after the map ?

Comment: I don't have experience with `.share()`, but based on [documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/refcount.html) (example available) function with side-effects would not be called on every subsription but only once.